# shrinking namespace to base

Tags: c++, c++20

Is there a way to "shrink a namespace"?

e.g.

`std::chrono::milliseconds` to `std::milliseconds` by the namespace alone?

i.e.

```
namespace std = std::chrono
```

<sup>(please disregard the fact that this is modifying `std`. this is just an example I think everyone can understand)</sup>

Comment: That would change the meaning of `std`, so no. You can shorten namespaces with an alias though.

Comment: How about inside the namespace? Like if I declare out namespaces within namespaces for organization, is there anyway to shrink it?

Comment: I think so. It'll be easier to understand what you mean if you show some code, even if it doesn't compile.

Comment: @cigien `namespace std { using namespace chrono; }` will that work?

Comment: @nowi: That would be adding something to namespace `std`, which is generally forbidden by C++'s rules.

Comment: @NicolBolas Correct. Please see the spoiler in the question.

Comment: Just in general, it's not helpful to ask a question like "How do I do X? (I don't mean literally X, I know X is bad, I just mean something like X? Come on people it's right there in the spoiler!)" Just ask "How do I do Y?" instead.

Comment: Title is literally `shrinking namespace to base`. What are you talking about @Barry? I put `e.g.` to mark an example

Comment: @nowi I have no idea what "shrinking namespace to base" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your own alias to `std::chrono`, external to `std`:

```
namespace chrono = std::chrono;
```

And then use `chrono::milliseconds`.

---

It's possible to collapse layers of namespaces by adding an internal namespace alias. The standard library does this:

```
namespace std {
    namespace ranges::views { /* views stuff */ }

    namespace views = ranges::views;
}
```

So that `std::ranges::views::filter` can also be accesses as `std::views::filter`.

But that doesn't help here because `milliseconds` is a type, not a namespace. The only way to collapse the contents of a namespace is with a using-directive (or equivalently, a whole lot of using-declarations):

```
namespace std {
    namespace chrono { /* chrono things */ }

    using namespace chrono;
}
```

Which isn't really a good idea because it could just break name lookup for things - especially if anything in `std::chrono` is named the same as something in `std`. This also completely defeats the purpose of having the nested namespace to begin with.

So the equivalent to the inner namespace alias would just be the outer namespace alias:

```
namespace std {
    namespace chrono { /* chrono things */ }
}
namespace chrono = std::chrono;
```

And now you write `chrono::milliseconds` instead of `std::chrono::milliseconds`, without having to break anything in any of those namespaces.

Alternatively, if you really want to just shove everything into the same namespace, do it into a different one:

```
namespace all {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
}
```

Although, as I said, questionable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to "shrink a namespace"?

You can give namespace an alias, or you can have `using namespace` declarations.

> e.g.
>
> std::chrono::milliseconds to std::milliseconds

Something like that is possible, but not for the `std` namespace because you may not put such declarations there.

But this is possible for example:

```
namespace my {
     using namespace std::chrono;
}
```

and this:

```
namespace my_chrono = std::chrono;
```

Comment: That doesn't really address the OP's concern. That approach would simply make it so `my::chrono::milliseconds` can be used instead of `std::chrono::milliseconds`.  Perhaps you meant something more like `namespace my { using milliseconds = std::chrono::milliseconds; }` instead?  Then `my::milliseconds` can be used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Fair enough. I didn't think it through to the end. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: That looks better, now `my::milliseconds` and `my_chrono::milliseconds` should work, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a namespace with some deeply nested name that you want to shorten (and it's a namespace you are allowed to modify). e.g:

```
namespace my {
  namespace deeply {
    namespace nested {
      namespace ns {
 // ...
}}}}
```

you can simplify it with a namespace alias:

```
namespace my {
  namespace easy = deeply::nested::ns;
}
```